# Spark List - alternatingItemColors - extend to bottom

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark

In the good old mx world, the alternatingItemColors extend all the way to the height of the list. In the spark list, it stops where the data ends. Does anyone know if there is an easy way to make the Spark list behave similar to the mx list? See the image below. there is white space below the list, this does not happen in the mx list.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficulty will depend on how flexible your solution must be, but in general I think your best bet would be to create a custom skin for this List.

### Create a custom skin

You can start by copying the Spark List skin ([spark.skins.spark.ListSkin](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/skins/spark/ListSkin.html)) and making some minor modifications to it:

```
<!-- AlternatingColorListSkin.mxml -->
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Metadata>
        [HostComponent("spark.components.List")]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal"/>
        <s:State name="disabled"/>
    </s:states>

    <s:Rect id="background" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor id="bgFill" color="0xEEEEEE"/>
        </s:fill>
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke id="borderStroke" weight="1"/>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <s:Group id="oddRowGroup" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" clipAndEnableScrolling="true"/>

    <s:Scroller id="scroller" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0" minViewportInset="1" hasFocusableChildren="false">
        <s:DataGroup id="dataGroup" itemRenderer="spark.skins.spark.DefaultItemRenderer">
            <s:layout>
                <s:VerticalLayout id="dataLayout" gap="0" horizontalAlign="contentJustify" requestedMinRowCount="5"/>
            </s:layout>
        </s:DataGroup>
    </s:Scroller>

</s:Skin>
```

In the code above I left out the portions of ListSkin that are irrelevant to this answer and I made these modifications:

- the background fill color is the color of the even rows (instead of white by default)
- I added 'oddRowGroup' to which we'll be adding some darker rectangles
- I gave the DataGroup's layout an id (`dataLayout`) so that we can easily access it later

### Add the odd row backgrounds

We'll now be adding the odd row backgrounds to `oddRowGroup` dynamically. Note that `oddRowGroup`'s left/right/top/bottom is 1 so that the row backgrounds will not overlap the main background's border. It also has `clipAndEnableScrolling` set to `true` which will cause any possible overlap of the last odd row to be clipped.

Now add the following code in a script block in the skin:

```
private var previousHeight:Number = NaN;

override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
    if (previousHeight != unscaledHeight) refreshBackground(unscaledHeight);
    previousHeight = unscaledHeight;
}

private function refreshBackground(height:Number):void {
    var rowHeight:Number = dataLayout.rowHeight;
    var maxRows:int = height / rowHeight / 2;
    oddRowGroup.removeAllElements();

    for (var i:int = 0; i < maxRows; i++) {
        var row:FilledElement = new Rect();
        row.left = row.right = 0;
        row.height = rowHeight;
        row.top = (i * 2 + 1) * rowHeight;
        row.fill = new SolidColor(0xdfdfdf);
        oddRowGroup.addElement(row);
    }
}
```

What happens here?
In `updateDisplayList` (which is called amongst others each time the List is resized), we check whether the height has changed. If it has, we refresh the odd row backgrounds.

We do so by removing all backgrounds that were drawn for the previous height.
We get the `rowHeight` from the DataGroup's layout, and we calculate the total number of required backgrounds. Then we create some `Rect`s based on these numbers and we add them to `oddRowGroup`.

### Limitations

The solution as it is, has some limitations. For instance the alternating colors are hardcoded (which can easily fixed by getting the right colors using `getStyle()`); it assumes there will be no override of the default layout (which is a `VerticalLayout`); it assumes `variableRowHeight` is off; and probably some more. But I think it's a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed answer, much appreciated. Was hoping there would be a quick flag or something that we missed, but will try this out.